# I'd like to implement glob function in C

Tags: c, unix

I'm trying to implement `ls` command with wildcards, `?` and `*`, not using glob function. I'm going to implement my own path generator matching wildcard pattern. But I don't know where to start from. First, I need to traverse directories. How can I traverse directories to match pattern string containing wildcards. For example, assume that pattern is `*/*`. I have to traverse `directories/entires` and then check whether pattern string matches the traversed path using `fnmatch()`. And there are many possible cases, `../*/*`, `*/../*`, `*/`, `*/*/*.out`, etc.
Is there any useful link? Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Why don't you see how the real ls command is implemented for inspiration.. its source code is available as a part of the core-utils package. Also: on Linux/UNIX, wildcards are handled by the shell, not by the program.

Comment: since shell handles wildcards, I'm going to set argv to the following. argv[1] = "\"*.c\"".

Comment: although i think it's perfectly fine to write this from scratch, you could always use fork() and exec( ls ) with redirected io to achieve a similiar result or as a starting point.

Comment: I have received homework which requires me to implement `ls` command with wild card. I can use `opendir`, `access`, and `fnmatch` to implement path generator.

Comment: Well, here's the link to coreutils source which contains ls, which I said should give a starting point: http://bit.ly/17g5ZBE And here's a copy of the code online for your reading pleasure: http://bit.ly/15h0BSv

Comment: I can't find out any code related with path generator in ls code in link.

Comment: Because, again, wildcards are handled by the shell, not by your program. The shell expands the wildcards into an actual path, which is passed to the program through argv, which you then use. Since I'm assuming that the shell will be executing your program, I'd imagine that you wouldn't have to do anything other than handle the expected input.

Comment: Yes. But it's a homework. I'm under constraint that the program has argv including `pattern` in two single quote. e.g) argv[1] = "'.c'", argv[2] = "'*/'". So my question is that how directory is traversed. traversed directory and argv[1,2] is passed to `fnmatch()` to compare traversed one with argv[1,2].

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to invent your own solution then. This is impractical in real use.